# Failing to pair Samsung Gear Iconx earbuds with macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, bluetooth, earbuds

I am trying to pair my Samsung Gear Iconx earbuds with my MacBook Pro via the Bluetooth UI. I put the earbuds very close to the MacBook Pro, but it seems the Mac is not able to discover them. Any ideas how I can get them to pair?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently those earbuds don’t go into discoverable mode unless you take them out of their special case and put them in your ears when the thing they were previously paired to is not around. And then they only stay discoverable for 3 minutes.

So put them in their case, make sure anything they’ve been paired with before is completely switched off or far far away, then take the earbuds out of the case, put them in your ears, and use macOS’s Bluetooth UI to try to discover them.

Answer (score 5):

Actually after trial and error I had to press the button on the back of the case for  some time until it starts to light up blue and red thats when it will show up on other devices

Comment: I have not found a way to quickly switch between a phone and the MacBook yet. It seems you would need to newly pair with the respective device on every switch. If anybody has a solution for that, that would be great.